# Is it possible to add a "." inside a Math.random

Tags: javascript

I hope your fine.

At this moment I have created a random generator, which return 2 digits then add a dot and finaly add to the right 5 other digits. But I was wondering if it was possible to generate a random number and add a dot randomly between the second or third digits.

So far I have tried, but this return a number and not a string type.
Thank you for helping :)

```
   randomdot = ".";

   lastDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 709999)

   randomdot = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3)

   finalresult = randomdot + lastDigits

   document.getElementById('b-coordinates').innerHTML = `${finalresult}`;
```

Here is the snippet of the current code :)

```js
function coordinates(){


  firstDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  lastDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19999)


  afirstDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  blastDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19999)

  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').innerHTML = `${firstDigits}.${lastDigits}, ${afirstDigits}.${blastDigits}`;

  document.getElementById('c-coordinates').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <style>


    #buttonid{

      margin-left: 43.5vw;
      margin-top: 30vh;
      width: 11em;
      height: 3.8em;
      background: orange;
      color: black;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 800;
      box-shadow: 6px 8px 12px #212121;
    }

    #buttonid:hover{
      background: pink;
    }

    #c-coordinates{
      margin-left: 39.5vw;
      margin-top: 8.2vh;
      font-size: 1.6em;
      color: yellow;
      text-shadow: 3px 5px 7px #212121;
    }

    #b-coordinates{
      margin-left: 41.5vw;
      margin-top: 6.9vh;
      font-size: 2em;
      color: pink;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 12px black;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 7.8em;
    }

  </style>
  <body>

    <button id="buttonid" type="button" onclick="coordinates()" name="button">Click Here</button>

    <h3 id="c-coordinates"> Pas de coordonnées à copier</h3>
    <h3 id="b-coordinates"></h3>


    <script src="ja.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
function coordinates(){


  firstDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  lastDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19999)


  afirstDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  blastDigits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19999)

  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').innerHTML = `${firstDigits}.${lastDigits}, ${afirstDigits}.${blastDigits}`;

  document.getElementById('c-coordinates').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: I Think This can help you it does look similar

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-39.php

Comment: I think it's going to do the trick, thank you ;) appreciated it. I didn't find this doc sorry..

Comment: do post your solution, and how you got it working it will help someone.. someday :)

Comment: so you want the integer part to be randomly either 2 or 3 digits?

Answer (score 1):

simply use : `(Math.random() * 100).toFixed(5)`

sample code

```js
const rCoord = () => (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(5)

setCoord.onclick = () =>
  {
  coord.innerHTML = `${rCoord()}<br>${rCoord()}`
  }
```

```html
<button id="setCoord">new coordinates</button>

<p id="coord"></p>
```

Comment: That's pretty smart I didn't thought about this. thank you for helping me, although I have chosen a harder path, I think I have solved my issue. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

you have many ways to achieve this, and maybe you are overthinking the solution, here I leave you two ways of doing what you want.

A manual way to do it, where you can change the length of the start number and end number would be something like this.

```js
const generateNumber = () => {

  // random generate number of 2 or 3 digits (between 10 and 999)
  const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 989) + 10;
  const strStart = start.toString();

  // generate random number of 5 digits
  let tail = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);

  const wholeNumber = start + '.' + tail;

  // this number can have 8 digits for example 875.19832 or 7 digits for example 96.12837
  return wholeNumber
}

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log(generateNumber());
}
```

the other way would be to automatically generate a number from 0 (1 digit) to 999(3 digits) and then use the function `toFixed` to fix the decimals that you want, like this.

```js
const generateNumber = () => {
  const number = Math.random() * 999;
  const fixed = number.toFixed(5);
  const str = fixed.toString();

  return str;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  console.log(generateNumber());
}
```

Comment: If you take a look at the snippet it's actually very close to what I have figured out, I think I kinda solve my issue I'm just working around it and will probably solve my issue. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

So this is finally what I came up with, if this could help someone someday. The code is not really well written but it's for my own use so I guess it's fine. Thanks to 'Nishant Sham Vispute' this was very helpful https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-39.php

1. Take your random generated number -> convert it to string then split it
2. Use regular expressions to split the generated number in two half and add the dot
3. Join the parts

```js
function coordsGen(){
  coordinates()
  coordinatestwo()

  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').innerHTML = `${
twoDigitsPartsA} ${twoDigitsPartsB} `;

  document.getElementById('c-coordinates').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('b-coordinates').style.display = 'block';
}



function coordinates(){

  firstCords =  Math.ceil(Math.random() * (999999 - 10000 + 1) + 1)

  twoDigitsPartsA = firstCords.toString().split(".");
  twoDigitsPartsA[0] = twoDigitsPartsA[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!(\d)))/, ".");
  twoDigitsPartsA.join(".");
}



function coordinatestwo(){

    secondCords = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (999999 - 10000 + 1) + 1)

  twoDigitsPartsB = secondCords.toString().split(".");
  twoDigitsPartsB[0] = twoDigitsPartsB[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!(\d)))/, ".");
  twoDigitsPartsB.join(".");
}
```